# Migrating localhost MySQL to AWS Oracle seems to wait for four hours

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration, amazon-rds

I am currently migrating a localhost [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database of quite some size to an [AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) server with Oracle. I am using the SQL Developer tool with an installed add-on feature for MySQL support. The migration process is going quite slow and from the diagnostics tools it seems that the space on the server is reduced (sign of data transfer) every fourth hour.

1. Is this due to the diagnostic tool or any constaint added to the server?
2. If it is a constraint on the server, how can I remove this so data can be transferred faster?

I have now been migrating for about 40 hours and just 2 gigabytes are transferred. It seems like the transfers are performed every fourth hour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your post but are you using the migration wizard in SQL Developer? Is it an online or offline migration?

An online migration for a large database will be very slow, as it is literally rebuilding your database one row at a time, including integrity checks, redo generation, index building, etc.